# Plotting graphs for MYSQL

Tags: mysql, chart

I was executing following command

```
mysqladmin ext -i1 -c3600
```

It produces valuable output but I want to use the output to plot graphs so that I can visualize inserts, updates, buffer and other stuff.

Anyone has any idea on how to use the output to plot graphs ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are values that you need to graph with absolute values, such as

- [Innodb_buffer_pool_bytes_dirty](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-status-variables.html#statvar_Innodb_buffer_pool_bytes_dirty)
- [Threads_connected](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-status-variables.html#statvar_Threads_connected)
- [Threads_running](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-status-variables.html#statvar_Threads_running)

There are also values whose delta needs to be calculated and graphed, such as

- [Queries](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-status-variables.html#statvar_Com_xxx)

  - Com_select
  - Com_delete
  - Com_update
  - etc ...
- Incoming and Outgoing Traffic

  - [Bytes_received](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-status-variables.html#statvar_Bytes_received)
  - [Bytes_sent](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-status-variables.html#statvar_Bytes_sent)

You should consider using [Nagios XI](https://assets.nagios.com/downloads/nagiosxi/docs/Offloading_MySQL_to_Remote%20Server.pdf) or [MONyog](https://www.webyog.com/) to do all that for you.

If you want to be a hero, use Google Charts

- [Google Chart API - A Real World Example](http://www.ajaxonomy.com/2008/web-20/google-chart-api-a-real-world-example)
- [Sample Chart You Need to Craft in a Bash Script Using the Deltas and Absolute Values](http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chs=300x225&chd=t:9,16,51,51,51,52,58,59,61,62,63,67,69,69,69,72,74,74,89,93,96,98,100,100%7C4,8,12,16,20,25,29,33,37,41,45,50,54,58,62,66,70,75,79,83,87,91,95,100&cht=lxy&chxt=x,y&chxr=0,0,155%7C1,0,24)

I used Google Chart a few times and got away from it. It does work, but you have a lot of coding to store the absolute values and calculate deltas for specific variables. Then, you script the URL from the values and render the URL in a browser.

## GIVE IT A TRY, HERO !!!